# What what does it mean when import is followed by a require?

Tags: typescript

The [raven documentation for Angular 2](https://docs.sentry.io/hosted/clients/javascript/integrations/angular2/) mentions the following es6 code snippet:

```
import Raven = require('raven-js');  // NOTE: "require" not "from"
```

They explicitly mentioned the require however I am not sure what this statement actually does and where it is documented.

Comment: It means that it's not ES6 but Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import Raven = require('raven-js');
```

is the original Typescript import syntax.

The new ES6 style import is now preferred ([since TS 1.5](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#es6-modules))

```
import * as Raven from 'raven-js'
```

These two syntaxes import an external library/module for which type definitions must be available, either as separate definition files referenced in `tsconfig.json` or as part of the library with a reference to them in the `typings` entry of its `package.json` (the `///<reference` syntax should be avoided).

Please note that, in a 'require' environment, such as commonjs,

```
const Raven = require('raven-js');
```

will make `Raven` available to the rest of the code as `any` (i.e. definitions will not be imported). This may be handy when trying to use a JS library for which you do not have (or do do want to craft) the definitions.

Answer (score 0):

The `import` with `require` comes from TypeScript's own module system. You can read about it in depth [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html).

It also mentions how to use different types of module syntaxes (CommonJS, Native ES6 Modules, etc)